# Internet Explorer 11 D3 javascript error - SCRIPT5 Access is denied

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to open this [D3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083#index.html) along with this [json](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json) on IE11, but the screen is just blank. When I Inspect Element to check console, it shows this error :

> SCRIPT 5 : Access is denied.
>   File: d3.min.js, Line: 1, Column: 10922

I tried many fixes like lowering security, allowing active content, adding specific tags in the html etc. and also looked at similar stackoverflow questions, but no luck.
It works fine in Firefox though.
How do I get it to run in IE?

Comment: Solution - I put the files on Sharepoint, and it worked.

Comment: Rebooting solved this for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution - I put the files on Sharepoint server, and it worked.
IE does not allow linking to files on local desktop due to some policy, but if it's part of IIS, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is inner security of IE 11. Microsoft auto detects 'harmful' script and file and denies access. Basically, You need to check the options tab, or try even try using:

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Tty also permission settings and make sure add-ons are allowed on your IE.

Comment: yeah this was one of the tags i tried adding earlier, and addons are allowed, and i lowered the security levels for all zones to the lowest. No luck..